# How to get distinct names and percent of the latest record there is no rowid

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJAe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx9Wv.png)

I wanted to get the distinct names and percent of the latest record(latest record by date)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and upate your question using [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73766904/edit).

Comment: PL/SQL is for Oracle, not MySQL. Which database are you using?